# Physics of slipping

Tags: forces, friction

Suppose I consider a hypothetical friction-less floor. Will I slip on this floor? I think not! At least not until you make an effort to move. Unless there is a tangential force, you will not slip. Is this correct?

If so, why do we slip on a soapy, oily or muddy surface? Can one stand on very slippery surface without falling as long as one does not move?

Comment: Re, "I think not...so why do we slip on a soapy, oily..."  You seem to say that it would be easier to stand on a perfectly frictionless surface than it would be to stand on a _nearly_ frictionless surface.  What is your reason for believing that?

Comment: @james large "You seem to say that it would be easier to stand on a perfectly friction-less surface than it would be to stand on a nearly friction-less surface": I didn't mean anything like that. I just thought whether it is nearly fiction-less or perfectly so shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can one stand on very slippery surface without falling as long as one does not move?

Yes, in theory you can, but no  in practice you will always be subject to involuntary movements, or outside forces, and as soon as you try to correct them, you will slip.

I would also ask how you would manage to get to any very slippery place? Even being lowered onto it by rope will an create an unstable equibrium for you, as soon as you stand on it, given it is extremely slippery.